# only remove punctuation for words not numbers

Tags: r, regex

I am using the `tm` package in R to remove punctuation.

```
TextDoc <- tm_map(TextDoc, removePunctuation)
```

Is there a way I can only remove puncutation if it has to do with a letter/word instead of a number?

E.g.

I want `performance. --> performance`
But I want `3.14 --> 3.14`

Example of how i want function to work:

```
wall, --> wall
expression. --> expression
ef. --> ef
A. --> A
name: --> name
:ok --> ok

91.8.10 --> 91.8.10
```

**EDIT:**

`TextDoc` is of the form:
[image: form of textdoc]

Comment: How exactly do you define "if it has to do with a letter/word"? It would be helpful if you could include more test cases in a [reproducible data format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used for testing.

Comment: updated with examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've completely revamped my answer based on your specification and [Anil's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67955818/5851018), which is much more widely applicable than what I originally had.

```r
library(tm)

# Here we pretend that your texts are like this
text <- c("wall,", "expression.", "ef.", ":ok", "A.", "3.14", "91.8.10",
          "w.a.ll, 6513.645+1646-5")

# and we create a corpus with them, like the one you show
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))

# you create a function with any of the solutions that we've provided here
# I'm taking AnilGoyal's because it's better than my rushed purrr one.

my_remove_punct <- function(x) {
  
  gsub('(?<!\\d)[[:punct:]](?=\\D)?', '', x, perl = T)

}

# pass the function to tm_map
new_corp <- tm_map(corp, my_remove_punct)

# Applying the function will give you a warning about dropping documents; but it's a bug of the TM package.


# We use this to confirm that the contents are indeed correct. The last line is a print-out of all the individual documents together.
sapply(new_corp, print)
#> [1] "wall"
#> [1] "expression"
#> [1] "ef"
#> [1] "ok"
#> [1] "A"
#> [1] "3.14"
#> [1] "91.8.10"
#> [1] "wall 6513.645+1646-5"
#> [1] "wall"                 "expression"           "ef"                  
#> [4] "ok"                   "A"                    "3.14"                
#> [7] "91.8.10"              "wall 6513.645+1646-5"
```

The warning you receive about "dropping documents" is not real as you can see by printing. An explanation is in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081415/transformation-drops-documents-error-in-r).

In the future, note that you can quickly get better answers by providing raw data with the function `dput` to your object. Something like `dput(TextDoc)`. If it is too much, you can subset it.

Comment: thanks for the help, how can I apply your code to the form my dataset TextDoc is in?

Comment: @user11015000, updated now by actually using the `tm` package.

Answer (score 5):

You may also try this `gsub('(?<!\\d)[[:punct:]](?=\\D)?', '', text, perl = T)` where text is your text vector.  Explanation of regex

- `(?<!\\d)` negative lookbehind for any digit character
- `[[:punct:]]` searches for punctuation marks
- `(?=\\D)` followed by positive lookahead for any non-digit character
- `?` 0 or once
- [check this](https://regex101.com/r/ASaFE6/1/) for regex demo

```r
text <- c("wall, 88.1", "expression.", "ef.", ":ok", "A.", "3.14", "91.8.10")

gsub('(?<!\\d)[[:punct:]](?=\\D)?', '', text, perl = T)
#> [1] "wall 88.1"  "expression" "ef"         "ok"         "A"         
#> [6] "3.14"       "91.8.10"


long_text <- "wall, 88.1 expression. ef. :ok A. 3.14 91.8.10"

gsub('(?<!\\d)[[:punct:]](?=\\D)?', '', long_text, perl = T)
#> [1] "wall 88.1 expression ef ok A 3.14 91.8.10"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Tried to make it less ugly but here is my best shot:

```
library(data.table)

TextDoc <- data.table(text = c("wall",
                      "expression.", 
                      "ef.",
                      "91.8.10",
                      "A.", 
                      "name:", 
                      ":ok"))

TextDoc[grepl("[a-zA-Z]", text), 
      text := unlist(tm_map(Corpus(VectorSource(as.vector(text))), removePunctuation))[1:length(grepl("[a-zA-Z]", text))]]
```

Which gives us:

```
> TextDoc
         text
1:       wall
2: expression
3:         ef
4:    91.8.10
5:          A
6:       name
7:         ok
```